# Automatically end Python process after running in REPL

Tags: python, windows, terminal, sublime-text-plugin

I often debug Python using a Sublime Python repl extension, and the processes often stack up without closing. Is there something I can append to the end of my code to automatically end the repl process? I can right click it to 'kill repl,' but am looking for an automatic way.

I have tried using exit() and sys.exit() but they do not terminate the processes. Frankly I'm not remotely aware of how REPL or terminals in general work under the hood.

Comment: What read–eval–print loop are you using and how was the process that's running created? This information is likely crucial to answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with sublime text, but from brief searches online on the most prominent REPL (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) it looks like the REPL is part of the sublime process which might be why exit() and sys.exit() aren't working. It looks like you can just close the window tab and that ends the process but i'm not 100% sure.

Although it might not be a solution to your specific issue (I can't comment on SO yet), if you are looking for an interactive local REPL for debugging and testing a good option might be [ptpython](https://pypi.org/project/ptpython/0.6/). It has autocomplete and you can use exit() since it's actually a separate python process, but it does require a separate terminal (unless there's a sublime integration).